# Compact Class DSL in python

Tags: python, class, singleton, properties, dsl

I want to have compact class based python DSLs in the following form:

```
class MyClass(Static):
    z = 3
    def _init_(cls, x=0):
        cls._x = x

    def set_x(cls, x):
        cls._x = x

    def print_x_plus_z(cls):
        print cls._x + cls.z

    @property
    def x(cls):
        return cls._x

class MyOtherClass(MyClass):
    z = 6
    def _init_(cls):
        MyClass._init_(cls, x=3)
```

I don't want to write `MyClass()` and `MyOtherClass()` afterwards. Just want to get this working with only class definitions.

```
MyClass.print_x_plus_z()
c = MyOtherClass
c.z = 5
c.print_x_plus_z()
assert MyOtherClass.z == 5, "instances don't share the same values!"
```

I used metaclasses and managed to get `_init_`, `print_x` and subclassing working properly, but properties don't work.
Could anyone suggest better alternative?
I'm using Python 2.4+

Comment: What's wrong with `MyClass().print_x_plus_z()`?  What's wrong with `c=MyOtherClass()`?  Why not simply use Python correctly?

Comment: or just write `MyClass=MyClass()` after each class.

Comment: You might consider this as a brain exercise.
I just want the most perfect universal DSL I can make.
I don't want to write neither MyClass=MyClass() or MyClass().member if this is possible.

Comment: I don't get how breaking the language creates a "most perfect universal DSL".  It seems mostly to create confusion.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  It's unclear and incomplete.  If you don't want to clarify it, perhaps you shouldn't be asking. 
 Please clarify the question so that it's possible to answer.  What are you trying to do?  Why subvert object definitions?  What's the point?

Comment: Are you intentionally using `_init_` instead of `__init__`?

Comment: S.Lott, question is clear and complete. I'm sorry that you don't want to understand it. Please read Alex's answer, he got me right.
I'll provide my solution soon. And yes, I'm intentionally using _init_ instead of __init__ cause I didn't know if it's possible to override it in metaclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give a *class* (as opposed to *its instances*) a property, you need to have that property object as an attribute of the class's metaclass (so you'll probably need to make a custom metaclass to avoid inflicting that property upon other classes with the same metaclass). Similarly for special methods such as `__init__` -- if they're on the class they'd affect the instances (which you don't want to make) -- to have them affect the class, you need to have them on the (custom) metaclass.  What are you trying to accomplish by programming everything "one metalevel up", i.e., never-instantiated class with custom metaclass rather than normal instances of a normal class?  It just seems a slight amount of extra work for no returns;-).